# Unreal Engine : Instanced Static Mesh doesn't rotate on instanciation

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently doing real time growing trees, and i'm using an instanced static mesh component for the foliage, since every leaf is unique. When I add an leaf instance to my component, I put a random rotation on it. But for some reason, this rotation is not set, all my leaves have a zerorotator. The scale is set, the transform too, but not the rotation.

Here is the code :

```
//Instanced static mesh component instanciation, as a component of the tree
foliage = NewObject<UInstancedStaticMeshComponent>(this);
foliage->SetWorldLocation(GetActorLocation());
foliage->RegisterComponent();
foliage->SetStaticMesh(data->leaves[treeType]);
foliage->SetFlags(RF_Transactional);
this->AddInstanceComponent(foliage);

//Adding a instance of foliage
const FTransform leafTrans = FTransform(
FMath::VRandCone(normals[branches[i].segments[j].firstVertice + 2], 2.0f).Rotation(),
vertices[branches[i].segments[j].firstVertice + 2], FVector::ZeroVector);

foliage->AddInstance(leafTrans);
```

I recently changed the Instanced Static Mesh Component, I beggined to put it on a child actor, and the rotation worked. But I had to remove it for an other issue.

I'm sure it's a small thing I'm missing, but I'm losing too much time searching on the internet, and there is not that much documentation on this subject...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the scale. For some reason, if it is set to zero, it also set the rotation to zero...